# Как получить имя и фамилию пользователя VK без дополнительного запроса?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, oauth

Возник такой вопрос: сделать так, чтобы vk при авторизации через oauth 2, помимо id, сразу возвращал имя и фамилию пользователя?

Попробовал в настройках указать первый запрос к api:

`users.get?user_id={viewer_id}&v=5.25`

Но, похоже, с oauth это не работает. Есть другие варианты, не делая дополнительный запрос к api со стороны сервера, заставить vk возвращать вместе с id имя и фамилию?

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, что приемлемо сделать правильный первый запрос к API, раз есть id пользователя:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get",
    data: {
        user_ids: '1',
        v: "5.26"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (e) {alert(e.response[0].first_name + ' ' + e.response[0].last_name);}
});
```